# Efficiently Read custom CSV Files into Python

Tags: python, csv, import

I am trying to learn Python and started with this task of trying to import specific csv files in a given folder into a Python Data Type and then further processing the data. 
       I am struggling with the part where the data needs to be imported into Python . I need this to be efficient. I tried a couple of things and attempted a couple of approaches based on suggestions provided in the forums and other web pages - all of them resulting in one problem or other . If any one can help solve this , the help would be greatly appreciated.

**Note: I have already imported pandas as pd**

**Approach 1** :

```
DF = pd.read_csv(FilePath)
```

This yields the following error :

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 13, saw 2

**Approach 2 :**

```
DF = pd.read_csv(FilPath, skiprows=3)
```

This also yields the same error :

> Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 13, saw 2

**Approach 3 :**

```
data = pd.read_csv(FilePath, error_bad_lines=False)
```

This skips every row and reads one character per line . This makes processing the data any further hard.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/32778128/Test.csv

If any one has any suggestions to fix this problem , I would greatly appreciate the help.

Best 
U

Comment: `pandas` is the way to go.  It's better suited for the way your data is arranged. and for skipping rows.  The other option with `csv` is to advance the reader twice to skip or assign the headers.  Some notes: use a `with` block to safely open and close files, and it's convention that variables are lowercase.

Answer (score 1):

When you say "DataFrame" what you should be using is the Pandas library. Pandas gives you the Pandas DataFrame where you can easily manipulate import csv files and start manipulating the data. You should look into the [pandas.read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) function specifically. It will do what you're asking and more. Look into the "skiprows" argument if you need to filter by row.

You can get a DataFrame object by doing the following:

```
import pandas

df = pandas.read_csv('boing.csv')  # Creates dataframe from specified CSV file
```

If you need more than that then you can refer to the documentation linked above, pandas.read_csv takes too many arguments to list here. I hope this helps.

Example with `skiprows`:

```
df = pandas.read_csv('boing.csv', skiprows=2)
```

This will give you a DataFrame skipping the first two rows of your CSV file. You can change 2 to any number of headers you have. When using `skiprows`, make sure the you are not skipping a row that is representative of the actual data in the file.

Comment: Apologies for not elaborating further in my question . I have tried this method as well . The above method as implemented in my case looks as follows 

import pandas as pd 
DF = pd.read_csv(FilePath, skiprows=3)

This yields the following error - 
Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 13, saw 2

Upon searching further to fix this error - I ended up here . 
data = pd.read_csv('file1.csv', error_bad_lines=False)

This reads the data correctly however it reads one character per row

Comment: I added a sentence to the end of my answer with another detail about `skiprows`. I hope it helps.

Comment: Using skiprows doesn't help unfortunately. 
@large_medium_pizza.

Comment: @UGuntupalli Try editing your question with what you want to do exactly, and try to add your CSV file so myself and others can try working with it.